# how to change font/background colors of a selected option permanently with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, colors, html-select, selected

I require the **selected option's font/background colors change permanently** to for example red/yellow after user completed the selection.

**Constraints:**

- Code must work in IE11.
- No jquery. Pure js.
- Form has id. Selects, options do not have id.
- Form has tens of selects.
- Solution does not have to be inline js.
- **If it is a must** for solution, I can add class to selects and/or options.

As an example assume "health" was selected from below. So "health" should be seen red/yellow after selection completed and clicked to a space in the page

I don't know js. I tried as below and did not work in ie11. Browser js is enabled. I couldn't find an existing Q/A proper for me.

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <select name="select1" onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].style.color='red'">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option style="color:#333;" value="1">Health</option>
        <option value="2">Wisdom</option>
</form>
```

- why my trial did not work?
- how to make it work while satisfying my constraints?

here is the jsbin link: https://jsbin.com/hubigarofa/1/edit?html,output

thanks, regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a seperate function and on call pass the element to that function using this

```js
function a(elem)
{
document.querySelector('select').style.backgroundColor = ""
document.querySelector('select').style.color = ""
elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].style.color='red'
if(elem.value=="1")
{

document.querySelector('select').style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
document.querySelector('select').style.color = "red"
}
}
```

```html
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <select name="select1" onchange="a(this)">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option style="color:yellow;" value="1">Health</option>
        <option value="2">Wisdom</option>
</form>
```

Comment: after i select option and select box closes (click to some space); colors are still the defaults. i tried js above and below my related html.do u have any chance to try your code in ie11?

Comment: i can alert with js so my js is enabled.

Comment: worked :) many thx. but why previous not worked? can u explain

Comment: Previously i wasnt sure if you wanted the bgcolor of the select to be yellow or the text of the selected option. If this is what you were looking for upvote and mark it as correct so it can help others too.